# loc for Categorical data in Pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have a dataset with a column that contains categories. I'd like combine certain categories into existing categories. I am trying to have a total of 11 categories by combining War into Action, History into Documentary, Science Fiction into Fantasy, etc.

This is the column info:

```
df.genre.value_counts()

Drama              9081
Comedy             6562
Action             3692
Horror             2087
Crime              1435
Documentary        1334
Thriller           1312
Adventure          1301
Romance             931
Animation           830
Fantasy             573
Science Fiction     502
Mystery             457
Family              395
Western             375
Music               324
War                 308
TV Movie            245
History             216
Foreign              60
Name: genre, dtype: int64
```

To try to combine values like History and Documentary, I previously used `loc` function but can't remember the proper code and keep getting an error.

Code I used (which is incorrect):

```
df.loc[df.genre["History"].value_counts().reset_index() = df.genre["Documentary"]] = "Documentary"

df.loc[df.genre["War"].value_counts().reset_index() = df.genre["Action"]] = "Action"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to build a map and then use `df.col.replace()`, see below.

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame(dict(genre=['War','Adventure','Action'], genre_update=['Action','Action','Action']))

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(genre=['War','Adventure','Action','Mystery'], val=[1,2,3,4]))

df['updated'] = df.genre.replace(dict(zip(df_map.genre, df_map.genre_update)))

|    | genre     |   val | updated   |
|---:|:----------|------:|:----------|
|  0 | War       |     1 | Action    |
|  1 | Adventure |     2 | Action    |
|  2 | Action    |     3 | Action    |
|  3 | Mystery   |     4 | Mystery   |
```

Note, you can use `df.col.map()` but that will replace unmapped values with NaN.

```
df['updated'] = df.genre.map(dict(zip(df_map.genre, df_map.genre_update)))

|    | genre     |   val | updated   |
|---:|:----------|------:|:----------|
|  0 | War       |     1 | Action    |
|  1 | Adventure |     2 | Action    |
|  2 | Action    |     3 | Action    |
|  3 | Mystery   |     4 | nan       |
```